# Would like to validate a reference to a container in an XML

Tags: xml, schematron

I have a config file written in XML.  I have XSD validation for most of it.  I would like to validate that a reference to a container within the same XML is valid (exists).  I would also like to validate a reference to a container in another XML is valid, but I'll ask that separately.

My container defines a "switch" as references to other specific containers.  Looks something like this.

```
<switch> name="SW-01" type="NORMAL">
    <in-left>I_SW-01R</in-left>
    <out-left>O_SW-01R</out_left>
    <in-right>I_SW-01N</in-right>
    <out-right>O_SW-01N</out-right>
</switch>
```

I would like to test to assure these containers exist.

Comment: Is <switch> the "container" that you're referring to? Does your document contain many <switch>s within a higher level root element that you did not show? Are you trying to validate the contents of the <in-left>, <out-left>, <in-right>, and <out-right> elements, or are you trying to validate the @name attribute of the <switch> element? If you can give more XML in your example, that would help, especially if you can provide enough XML to illustrate a scenario that should pass validation and a scenario that should fail validation.

Comment: So yes, I have many switch containers each looking like the one I detailed.  Each of the elements within the switch container (in the sample xml I showed) refer to another container they identifies the specific details.  My <in-left> container defined earlier looks like this: 
````<input-point id="SW-77SP1" type="TKN" name="I_SW-77TK3">
````````<switch>SW-77</switch>
````````<tseg>NONE</tseg>
````````<device>1</device>
````````<iopt>1</iopt>
````````<invert>0</invert>
````</input-point>

Comment: Sorry - new at this.  Not sure how to enter code in a comment.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like to check the content of each child element of each `<switch>` to ensure that it references an existing element somewhere in the document that has an `@id` that matches. (For example, if you have `<in-left>I_SW-01R</in-left>`, then you expect that somewhere there is `<input-point id="I_SW-01R"...`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, Joshua, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<sch:rule context="switch/*">
    <sch:assert test=". = //@id">
        <sch:name/> should reference an element that has a matching "id" attribute.
    </sch:assert>
</sch:rule>
```

The rule context ("switch/*") causes the rule to fire on all elements that are a child of a "switch" element. The assert test will pass if the content of the element (".") is equal to the value of any "id" attribute in the document ("//@id").

On large documents, this rule may not perform well, because the assert test looks through the entire document to find "id" attributes. If you know the expected structure of your document, I recommend that you make the Xpath in the assert test more specific.

Comment: Thank you Joshua, good information.  I'm going to try this as soon as I can get back to that project.  I do have a rather large document, so I just might have to be specific when I put in the reference.  Thanks for the help.